# Button inside the CollectionView repeating the first cell information

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, cell

i am creating images app from my Wordpress website's json using swift , i have created CollectionView and every cell displaying images and working fine but i want to add show comment in every cell for each post, its showing the exact comments for every post/cell but when i click on it it shows the comments of very first post of collection view. this is my code to show comments and for clickable button.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! homeViewCell

    let url = dataArray[indexPath.row]["thumbnail_images"]["medium"]["url"].stringValue
    cell.imageArticle.sd_setImage(with: NSURL(string: url) as URL?, placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "empty.png"))
     cell.nametag.text = String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["tags"][0]["title"].stringValue)
    cell.nametagg.text =  String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["categories"][0]["title"].stringValue)



    cell.fbButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeController.fbClick), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.commentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeController.comment), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.commentButton.setTitle("\(dataArray[indexPath.row]["comment_count"].stringValue) comments", for: .normal)
    cell.leaveComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeController.leavecomment), for: .touchUpInside)




   cell.contentline.text = String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["excerpt"].stringValue)





 return cell
}
```

and this is the code for button click

```
@objc func comment(_ sender: Any) {

  let vc = CommentViewController()
    vc.dataArray = dataArray[indexPath.row]["comments"].array
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


}
```

i hope you understand my question, thanks

Comment: could you please share whole function instead of a line? Is `comment(_:)` function compiled correctly?

Comment: edited the question , please check @emrcftci

Comment: yes comment function is working perfect but the problem is its showing the same comments for every post/cell @emrcftci

Comment: what is the `indexPath.row` in `comments(_:)` function? where it comes from?

Comment: if i don't add indexPath.row then its not getting the json data @emrcftci

Comment: and i have this to make it work outside of collectionview . let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) , i think here is the problem @emrcftci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the `indexPath` as a global variable and it's value is `NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` as you said.

in `comments(_:)` function you've used `indexPath.row` but this `row` is `0` so it is first post's comments.

You don't need to set `tapgesture` to `cell`'s button.

---

In `homeViewCell` you should create `IBAction` for the button and call closure when it triggered ->

```swift
class homeViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    public var didTapComment: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func didTapCommentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        didTapComment?()
    }
}
```

---

Set `didTapComment`'s action in `cellForItemAt` like this ->

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! homeViewCell

    cell.didTapComment = { [weak self] in
        let vc = CommentViewController()
        vc.dataArray = dataArray[indexPath.row]["comments"].array
        self?.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    let url = dataArray[indexPath.row]["thumbnail_images"]["medium"]["url"].stringValue

    cell.imageArticle.sd_setImage(with: NSURL(string: url) as URL?, placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "empty.png"))
    cell.nametag.text = String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["tags"][0]["title"].stringValue)
    cell.nametagg.text =  String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["categories"][0]["title"].stringValue)

    cell.fbButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeController.fbClick), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.commentButton.setTitle("\(dataArray[indexPath.row]["comment_count"].stringValue) comments", for: .normal)
    cell.leaveComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeController.leavecomment), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.contentline.text = String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["excerpt"].stringValue)

    return cell
 }
}
```

---

**Remove followings;**

- `cell.commentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeController.comment), for: .touchUpInside)` line from `cellForItemAt`
- `@objc func comment(_ sender: Any)` function
- `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)`

Comment: sorry for asking, where to put class CustomCell ? in HomeViewCell.swift ? @emrcftci

Comment: Create separate `CustomCell.swift` file and paste it to here.

Comment: I've updated the `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell` line please check my updated answer

Comment: do i need to create that bcz i already have class homeViewCell: UICollectionViewCell ?